# void pointer to a dynamically allocated class

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I'm trying to pass a void* to a function, then inside that function make the pointer point to an dynamically created object.  This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working:

main:

```
int main()
{
  void* objPtr;

  setPtr(objPtr);
}
```

setPtr:

```
void setPtr(void*& objPtr)
{
  objPtr = new Obj1; 
  (*objPtr).member1 = 10; //error: expression must have pointer-to-class type
}
```

Obj1:

```
struct Obj1
{
  int member1;
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" will not cut it.  What unexpected behavior do you see, or what compiler error are you getting?  You probably need parentheses in `new Obj1()` but I bet there are other problems too.

Comment: when I try to assign a (public) member variable a value, it says that the expression must have pointer-to-class type

Comment: @LoganBesecker That problem is unrelated to the code given above. You'll need to show the code that defines the class and its members.

Comment: Is there a reason why you pass the pointer as `void *` instead of `Obj1 *`?

Comment: @jogojapan I have an array of void* so I can have different indexes of the array pointing to different object types

Comment: Ok. You can certainly do that. But it implies giving up type safety; so, as a final comment: You may want to consider alternatives, such as a [polymorph class hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1579801/777186) or using `boost::variant<>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, sure: a `void*` doesn't point to a class type, so can't be used to access members. C++ is statically typed. The compiler sees a `void*` and that's that. It won't try to figure out what type of object the pointer actually points to -- you have to tell it, with a cast:

```
objPtr->whatever; // fails: objPtr is not a pointer-to-class-type

((actual_type*)objPtr)->whatever; // okay: cast to actual_type*
```

Well, that's the C programmer in me. Some folks prefer to use `static_cast` here:

```
static_cast<actual_type*>(objPtr)->whatever; // okay: cast to actual_type*
```

However you do it, though, you have to be sure that `objPtr` in fact points to an object of type `actual_type`.

Comment: I didn't see the "(objPtr*).member1 = 10;" part when I started to write my answer

Comment: oh, earlier I was trying (actual_type*)objPtr->whatever but didn't have the parentheses around the whole outer pair of parentheses

Comment: @LoganBesecker - `(actual_type*)objPtr->whatever` says to pretend that the type of `objPtr->whatever` is `actual_type*`. It's an easy mistake to make when you're first getting into this stuff.

Comment: Thank you Pete! I do have one more question though, which is a little off topic.  Is there any difference between the C and C++ way of typecasting?  I was initially taught the C style but now I'm wondering if there are any subtle(or not so subtle) differences between how the two work.

Comment: @Logan: The C++ casts are stricter than C casts.  You can't use `static_cast` to remove a `const` qualifier (you need to use `const_cast` for that), among other restrictions.  C-style casts are catchall that can perform all of the functions of the different C++ casts.  It's also much easier to search a code base for instances of keywords like `static_cast` than for `(typename)`, although honestly I've never seen anyone actually do that.  One downside of C++ casts is that they require more typing.

Comment: oh, interesting; I had never understood why people would do the extra typing but now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The problem of the question owner turns out to be different, this answer stands for the same thing with implemented with pointer to pointers. Consult the real answer of Pete Becker about proper casting.

```
int main()
{
  void* objPtr;

  setPtr(&objPtr);
}
```

setPtr:

```
void setPtr(void** objPtr)
{
  *objPtr = new Obj1; //where Obj1 is user defined class type
}
```

What I do here is just C-way pointer passing, setPtr function takes a pointer to a void pointer, and sets the void pointer as intended.

Comment: Did you mean to declare the function as `setPtr(void ** objPtr)`?

Comment: Won't compile: can't dereference a `void*`.

Comment: Is `**` dereferencing the pointer..? What does it do exactly?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - the code, now, is essentially the same as the original code, except that the address to be modified is passed with a pointer instead of a reference. This doesn't affect the actual problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker: that would be good information to have in your answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - it's not my answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker: sorry, it would _still_ be good to have more information in the answer - which is what I asked for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders How can I explain more?